# What is the correct way to handle AJAX driven DOM changes in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I realize that "the correct way" is subjective but I think this is a specific enough question that there is a best practices approach to it.

I'm new to Angular and trying to understand what the prescribed mechanism is for the following.

I have a series of dependant `<SELECT>`s which don't have any data associated with them at the time of launch.

The first one goes and fetches some items (that need to be populated as `<option>`s) via `$http` and the resulting JSON response is used to populate the next `<SELECT>`.

Depending on the response there may or may not be subsequent `<SELECT>`s, meaning if the user chooses option 1 there is a follow up choice but if they choose option 2 there isn't and I don't wish to hard code all the possible `<SELECT>`s into my model, I need it to be elastic.

So... from what I'm reading, the `controller` is not the right place to deal with this, and I should use a `directive`, though I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how exactly to handle the specifics of modifying the DOM as necessary to introduce new `<SELECT>`s as required. Additionally I'm not clear on where I should do my AJAX calls and how to connect them to whatever it is that will respond by modifying the UI.

I'm hoping someone can point me to some effective tutorial on how to deal with this (or similar) scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right that you need to use a directive to do the DOM manipulation, but in this case I don't think you'll have to write any of your own, you can use the built in ones that angular provides.

You should also stick to the best practice of providing your data (in this case, `option` values etc.) through a service. I'm going to assume you can handle the service side of things yourself. Because I am lazy I will just manually enter the data into the scope in my controller (you will still need a minimal controller to get the data from the service to the scope).

> The first one goes and fetches some items (that need to be populated as `<option>`s) via `$http` and the resulting JSON response is used to populate the next `<SELECT>`.

It's not clear if you've worked out how to do this already or not, but you'll want to use the [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive:

Provided you have data like this:

```
[
  { key: "Ford fiesta", value: "fordFiesta" }, 
  { key: "Audi TT", value: "audiTT" }
]
```

You can use the following
markup:

```
<select ng-model="selection" 
        ng-options="options.label as (options.key, options.value) in options">
```

Again, I'm being lazy so I used a simpler markup later where the key is the same as the value.

> Depending on the response there may or may not be subsequent `<SELECT>`s, meaning if the user chooses option 1 there is a follow up choice but if they choose option 2 there isn't and I don't wish to hard code all the possible `<SELECT>`s into my model, I need it to be elastic.

For this you will need a more complex data structure than simply the array of options. For my example I devised something like the following:

```
[ 
  {
    modelName: "apples"
    title: "Do you like apples?"
    options: [ "yes", "no" ]
    followUps: [
      {
        modelName: "appleType"
        condition: "yes"
        title: "Do you prefer Granny smiths or snow white?"
        options: ["Granny Smith", "Snow White"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    modelName: "pears"
    title: "Do you like pears?"
    options: [ "yes", "no" ]
  }
]
```

`modelName` will be how we save the results, `followUps` are dependent `selects` that are shown if the answer is `condition`.

You can then make use of `ng-repeat` to loop through this array.
Note the below code is [Jade](http://jade-lang.com):

```
div.question(ng-repeat="select in selects")
  span.title {{select.title}}
  select(ng-model="results[select.modelName]", 
         ng-options="option for option in select.options")
  div.subquestion(ng-repeat="subselect in select.followUps", 
                  ng-show="!subselect.condition || 
                            subselect.condition == results[select.modelName]")
    span.title {{subselect.title}}
    select(ng-model="results[subselect.modelName]", 
       ng-options="option for option in subselect.options")
```

Essentially what you are doing is repeating your `title` followed by the `select` populated with the `options` (using `ng-options`), as well as all the `followUps` selects, but we control the visibility of the `followUp` selects based on whether the answer matches the `condition` or not using the `ng-show` directive.

This could be neatened up significantly (make your own directive with a template), and also made tolerant to an infinite number of layers of `followUps`, but hopefully this puts you on the right track?

See it working in **[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rXDr8jSyHvvg2hIWrHtk?p=preview)**.

Comment: You should also clear the value of subselect results if the user answers them, but then subsequently changes his mind about the parent question. Again, worth pointing out this is a demonstration of a concept and not a fully fledged approach!

Comment: I think I can make use of some of this (along with the other answer from Joshua Robinson, however, the part that I believe won't work (unless Angular is pure magic) is that the tree of selects is 100% dynamic so if a user is 4 selects deep and goes to the 1st select and changes their option, the only possible feedback is for select 2 to redraw its choices (or go away entirely if there are no 2nd level choices) and for selects 3 and 4 to go away since they are dependant on select 2's choice being made, so, I don't see how `followUps` can exist statically... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: That is possible but it needs to be slightly smarter than the example I have given. I will expand my answer once I get some time (maybe Monday)

Comment: I have it working now... your answer is actually very very close. I'll give you the green checkmark and if you feel the need to expand on the answer, feel free.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good video from the AngularJS conference in Salt Lake City... he covers some of what you are interested in within 20 min.

http://youtu.be/tnXO-i7944M?t=15m20s

AJAX request belongs in a factory, and that factory is injected in the controller as a dependency.

EDIT: So totally missed the guts of your question, sorry about that. You would setup the select using the ng-repeat directive like so:

```
<select ng-repeat="select in selects">
  <option ng-repeat="option in select.options" handle-fetch-select>{{ option }}</option>
</select>

app.factory('selectFactory', function (['$http']){
    var factory = {};

    factory.getSelects = function(){
        return $http.get('/selects.json');
    }

    factory.getSomeOtherSelect = function(){
        return $http.get('/otherSelects.json');
    }

    return factory;
});

app.controller('SelectController', function( ['$scope', 'selectFactory'] ){
    $scope.selects = [];

    init();

    function init(){
        selectFactory.getSelects().success(function(data){
            //would be $scope.selects = data; just mocking a response
            $scope.selects = [ { label : 'Foo', options : ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3']} ]};
        });
    }
});

app.directive('handleFetchSelect', function(['$scope', 'selectFactory']){
   return function(scope, element, attrs){
       element.bind('click', function(){
           //
           //Add logic to determine if a fetch is required or not
           // 
           //if (noFetchRequired)
           //    return;

           //determine which selects to request from server
           switch (expression) {
               case (expression1) :
                   selectFactory.getSomeOtherSelect.success(function(returnedArrayOfSelects){
                       scope.apply(function(returnedArrayOfSelects){
                           scope.selects.concat(returnedArrayOfSelects); 
                       });
                   }).error(function(){});
                   break;
           }
       }
   })
});
```

Didn't debug this stub so... <-- disclaimer :) Hopefully you get the idea.